# gtsummary: stack a data frame?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I've been using the fantastic gtsummary package to merge and stack tables. However, I'm stuck with the following use-cases.

Is there a way to transpose the output of the following code (from the package tbl_summary help page) so that instead of the column headers being "25% percentile" and "75% percentile" and the row names "Drug A" and "Drug B", these are switched so that the columns become "Drug A" and "Drug B" with the percentiles as rows in the table?   My aim is to subsequently stack this table onto a table I've already generated so that these results are shown.

```
tbl_survfit(survfit(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ trt, trial), probs = c(0.25, 0.75))
```

[output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erf7i.png)

On a similar note, if I were to assemble a data frame of values generated outside gtsummary is it possible to to stack or merge it onto a tbl_summary object (similar to the way in which tbl_stack or tbl_merge work)?

Thanks for any pointers,

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

1. You can convert any gtsummary object to a tibble to perform more manipulation if you need.  Here's an example that would transpose your results:

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)

fit <- survfit(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ trt, trial)

tbl_survfit(fit, probs = c(0.25, 0.75)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  dplyr::slice(-1) %>%
  t()
#>                    [,1]          [,2]         
#> **Characteristic** "Drug A"      "Drug B"     
#> **25% Percentile** "17 (16, 20)" "15 (13, 17)"
#> **75% Percentile** "— (—, —)"    "— (—, —)"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

2. You *can* add any rows or columns to a gtsummary table, but you do need a bit of knowledge about the internals as to not break existing structures.  Every gtsummary object is a list, and there are two important pieces: `.$table_header` and `.$table_body`. The `.$table_body` is the data frame that is printed, and `.$table_header` are formatting instructions.  You can add rows to `.$table_body`, just make sure the types are the same before stacking and most of the time, you should be ok.  Adding columns is a bit trickier, but you can give it a shot as well! There are details here: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gtsummary_definition.html

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks!  For 1) is it possible to convert the tibble to a gtsummary object so that it may be stacked with an existing object? When I convert to a data frame and call tbl_summary I can't see how this may be achieved. The resulting table doesn't show the values of the percentiles but rather the n of them

Comment: Once we convert a gtsummary object to a tibble, it can't be converted back to a gtsummary obejct.